# iTunes COM - add track to playlist

Tags: c#, itunes-sdk

I'm using the iTunes COM for retreiving information about the playlists that the user created. My goal is to add a new song to the library and then to the given playlist. That is what I have now:

```
public static void AddTrack(IITPlaylist playlist, PlaylistItem item, string path)
{
    foreach (var track in AppClass.LibraryPlaylist.Tracks.Cast<IITTrack>().ToList())
    {
        if (track.Kind == ITTrackKind.ITTrackKindFile)
        {
            var fileTrack = track as IITFileOrCDTrack;
            if (fileTrack?.Location == path || fileTrack?.Name == item.Title)
                return;
        }
    }

    AppClass.LibraryPlaylist.AddFile(path);
    // Add new song to playlist here
}
```

However there is no proper documentation out there about adding songs to a playlist. The field `IITPlaylist.Tracks` is read only otherwise I would add the song to this collection.

Answer (score 2):

it's a little bit late, but maybe it will be usefull for someone.

```
IITUserPlaylist playlist= (IITUserPlaylist)AppClass.LibrarySource.Playlists.ItemByName["PlaylistName"];
playlist.AddTrack(track);
```